# Searching with words one character long (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a table Books in my MySQL database which has the columns Title (varchar(255)) and Edition (varchar(20)). Example values for these are "Introduction to Microeconomics" and "4".

I want to let users search for Books based on Title and Edition. So, for example they could enter "Microeconomics 4" and it would get the proper result. My question is how I should set this up on the database side.

I've been told that FULLTEXT search is generally a good way to do things like this. However, because the edition is sometimes just a single character ("4"), full text search would have to be setup to look at individual characters (ft_min_word_len = 1).. This, I've heard, is very inefficient.

So, how should I setup searches of this database?

UPDATE: I'm aware the CONCAT/LIKE could be used here.. My question is whether it would be too slow.  My Books database has hundreds of thousands of books and a lot of users are going to be searching it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your application, where you're interested in *just* title and edition, I suspect that using a `FULLTEXT` index with `MATCH/AGAINST` and reducing the `ft_min_word_len` to 1 would not have that much impact performance-wise (if you were data was more verbose or user written content, then I might hesitate).

The easiest way to check is to change the value, `REPAIR` the table to account for the new `ft_min_word_len` and rebuild the index, and do some simple benchmarking.

Having said that, for your application, I might consider looking into [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). It's definitely going to be magnitudes faster, and your content is relatively static, so a delay between re-indexing (Sphinx's main drawback IMO) isn't an issue.  Plus, with careful usage of the [wordforms](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms) and [exceptions](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-exceptions), you could map things like 4/four/fourth/IV all to the same token for improved searching.

Answer (score 3):

here are the steps for solution

1) read the search string from user.

2) make the string in to parts according to space(" ") between the words.

3) use following query for getting the result

SELECT * FROM books WHERE Title LIKE '%part[0]%' AND Edition LIKE '%part[1]%';

here part[0] and part[1] are separated words from the given word

the PHP code for the above could be

```
<?php 
     $string_array=explode(" ",$string); //$string is the value we are searching
     $select_query="SELECT * FROM books WHERE Title LIKE '%".$string_array[0]."%' AND Edition LIKE '%".$string_array[1]."%';";
     $result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($select_query));
?>
```

for $string_array[0] it could be extended to get all the parts except last one which can be applied for the case "Introduction to Microeconomics 4"

Comment: The problem with splitting on words is that titles have spaces, so you can't know if it's an edition or a title.

Of course, the LIKE method could be used by doing a CONCAT() on Title and Edition in the LIKE comparison.

My question is basically-- would this go to slow?  I hear that people use FULLTEXT because LIKE is so slow.  There are hundreds of thousands of books in my db, and a lot of people will be using the database.